Vee validate v4 keep errors on component unmount
Is it possible to persist error when component that uses useField gets unmounted?
For instance, parent component creates form context using useForm. Child component has input field and uses useField to interact with parent component form. If child component gets unmounted, value of that field and errors get removed. It is possible to keep value by using keepValuesOnUnmounted property, but what about errors?

Note - using validateOnMount on child component useField is not an option I'm looking for as I do not want to validate field on initial component mount.
